# Error : Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' while running React Native Project

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

I have got an error while trying to run my React Native project.

```
react-native run-android
```

Error looks like

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'E:\IT tasks\android\ninja-react-native\android\local.properties'.
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add **SDK**(sdk.dir) location path in local.properties file:

For windows users:

```
sdk.dir = C:\\Users"MyUserName"\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

For Mac users:

```
sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk
```

For Linux users:

```
sdk.dir = /home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk
```

Replace Username with your's users Name. And check that sdk forlder name is Sdk or sdk, replace with it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add your Sdk path as shown in image..